# When redirecting to another constructor in Dart, is it required to provide all the arguments?

Tags: constructor, dart

So, in Ruby, if I call super without arguments, it automatically passes all the arguments from the current method to super. Is this possible to do in Dart?

Example how it's done:

```dart
class SomeClass {

  SomeClass(arg1, arg2) {}
  SomeClass.build(arg1, arg2) : super(arg1, arg2);

}
```

Could it be done like this:

```dart
class SomeClass {

  SomeClass(arg1, arg2) {}
  SomeClass.build : super;

}
```

or in some similar way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you have to provide all the arguments.